# How do I stop HTMLpurifier from escaping PHP shorthand syntax examples in markdown?

Tags: php, markdown, htmlpurifier, htmlspecialchars

I'm using markdown and HTMLpurifier and I want to have examples of shorthand PHP (`<?= $variable ?>`) in the markdown code (using the indent syntax) however HTMLpurifier is not recognizing the tag `<` as an allowed element and is escaping it.

Any idea what config option I need to enable in HTMLpurifier to stop it escaping this?

Comment: This sounds like a funny interaction between our smiley preservation code and escaping :-) I'll look into it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's currently unsupported, you might be interested in joining this old thread from [HTMLpurifier forums - PHP shorthand tag](http://htmlpurifier.org/phorum/read.php?2,1988)

Another solution is to run your own str_replace to restore php sections if that is feasible and doesn't cause any security holes.